# php images change

Tags: php, html

Hi I was wondering what php code I can use that would allow my page to contain more than one image that changes. I would like the php code to output the HTML  tag. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: You have so many downvotes because you are not precise enough, and you should provide what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

you need to output all images to the browser from PHP, then use Javascpt to change the pictures. PHP is for server side scripts, the change you are talking about requires Client Side procxessing, ie Javascript. Do a search for jQuery image changer for some ideas

Answer (score 0):

The kind of mechanism you are referring to is often called a slideshow or a carousel, and it is done with javascript. Google "jQuery slideshow" or "jQuery carousel" and you'll find plenty of those.

If you need something simple, I suggest you the tiny the jQuery plugin [tiny carousel](http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel/).

Scroll to the `How To` section to know how to set it up.
Then, to change the images with php, you will need to do something like this:

```
<div id="slider-code">
    <a class="buttons prev" href="#">left</a>
    <div class="viewport">
        <ul class="overview">
           <?php foreach(glob('slideshow/*.jpg') as $imagePath): ?>
              <li><img src="$imagePath" /></li>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="buttons next" href="#">right</a>
</div>
```